# Any exercise to extend my finger flexibility?

Tags: guitar, exercises

When playing guitar, the fingers need to be extended flexibly in order to hit the right part of a string. Is there any exercise to make them more flexible when I am not playing guitar?

Comment: I don't have any particular answer but I know this: Better be careful when trying to come up with alternative offline exercises. It often does harm than good due to the mismatch between the real playing and the emulated one.

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to match the title. You really don't want to be trying to extend your tendon unless you already have a problem with your fingers. I'll leave an answer, but can you confirm what you actually mean?

Answer (score 2):

The single best thing you can do to improve flexibility, speed or strength for playing guitar is to **play the guitar**. A lot.

Try different styles as this will provide bbth a benefit from speed and strength, but also open you up to different types of music, eg fingerpicking, classical, flamenco, rock, metal etc